# C# XDocument stuck in memory

Tags: c#, xml, memory-management

Basically, I'm reading multiple xml files, recovering some items from it then next file, until all files are done and then I do my thing on collected items.

Problem is each file is ~50mb and I may have up to 70 to take on a single operation, plus on every loop memory usage (in visual studio's inspector) bumps ~180mb (around 800mb RAM usage for 5 files) so I might never have enough RAM to handle it, memory exceeded errors and all that...

I thought of using a yield return to work on every item as it appears but I need to get them all sorted before working on it.

Here is some sample code if it helps, tried setting my doc to null as found on some answers on SO but to no success...

```
class MyClass
{
    List<string> sourceFiles // All my XML input files
    List<XElement> listItem  // items to get from XML files

    /...

    static void FillListItem()
    {
        bool found = false;
        foreach (var sourceFile in sourceFiles)
        {
            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(sourceFile);
            foreach (var inventory in xdoc.Descendants("INVENTORY"))
            {
                if (/*Checks if current item is valid*/)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //...
                        listItems.Add(inventory);
                        found = true;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Logs.LogReject(Filenames.rejectInvalid, inventory, e);
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                else Logs.LogReject(Filenames.rejectConfig, inventory);
            }
            xdoc = null; //doesn't seem to change anything...
            if (!found)
                Logs.LogInfo("No corresponding field in " + sourceFile);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to add a copy of the `inventory` node to your list.  Adding the node itself is probably retaining references to its originating `XDocument`, keeping the whole thing in memory.

Comment: don't just store anything off of it - you should convert it to your model.

Comment: @Amy So like create a XElement foo = inventory; list.add(foo); rather than directly adding the inventory object itself? I'll try that.

Comment: @Phoque No, that does not make a copy.  You're just storing a reference in a variable and adding that same reference to your list, which is precisely what you're doing now.

Comment: I don't think copying the `inventory` node will help, but you need to do *something* to detach it from its parent

Comment: You can use `inventory.Remove()` to detach the node from its parent.

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria I guess you mean at the end of the foreach (but inside) this then gives me a null reference exception since it alters the xdocument the foreach is looping on

Comment: @Phoque Looking at your code, and with minimal work, you can simply do `xdoc.Descendants("INVENTORY").ToArray()` and call `inventory.Remove()` inside the try.

Comment: using a XElement foo = new XElement(inventory); as found in https://stackoverflow.com/a/24996516/9734355 doesn't do anything noticable on single file operations, but on 6 files I peaked at 480mb before it started going down to 150 progressively, so this seems like the thing to do in my case

@AlessandroD'Andria I will try this and post the comparison results